# Wordpress custom logout button on mobile screens

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-admin

I have made custom Logout button, instead of Howdy "User Name" and other options, which are located in the upper right corner. The problem that I have is that I am unable to keep this button (link) on the `screens below 783px` because admin bar changes.

[image: responsive]

And this is how it looks on mobile screens, the first picture is logged as an admin:

[image]

And this is how it looks for the regular users (subscribers):
[image]

So, I would like to fit the "Logout" button on the smaller screens also. Also, if it's possible, I would disable the buttons for the admin users (Customize, Comments, Edit...), so "Logout" can fit.

This is the code I used to create custom Logout, in my functions.php

```
 function custom_logout_link() {
global $wp_admin_bar;
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'id'    => 'wp-custom-logout',
    'title' => 'Logout',
    'parent'=> 'top-secondary',
    'href'  => wp_logout_url()
) );
$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('my-account');
$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('search');}
```

Comment: you're trying to do something weird, if your goal is to just fit the `logout` into the small screens. use css to make icons smaller, fit them on the screen, or fit them into 2 lines. there are a lot of possibilities to reach your target just with css

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan the main problem is that I am unable to put the "logout" on the screen at all. Any ideas?

Comment: yes, I provide 2 of them above. but can't be more detailed just because don't have html/css markup of your admin menu